# SQL UPDATE HWID WHERE LICENSEKEY

Tags: sql, project, hwid

Okay so I have a project on going and people pay for licenses and once a license is activated from the project it auto enters there hwid into the mysql DB.

So what I'm trying to do is for instance if column license key consists of license key "TEST-TEST-TEST=T" then set the hwid = "Not Set".

I've tried this sql query for instance.

UPDATE `table-name-here` SET `hwid`= 'Not Set' WHERE `licensekey` = 'TEST-TEST-TEST=T'

and the sql command will then return hwid value not to be set again.

Can any sql experts give me a hand on this please?
Appreciated.

Comment: Can you please put some table entries here with expected result ? So that i can write script for you.

Comment: There is only one table with 4 columns, but what I'm trying to do is in the table change hwid value to NOT SET where licensekey value is TEST-TEST-TEST=T

Comment: Query that you written should work properly. Thats way i asked for some sample rows so that we can investigate more.

Comment: Sample rows are username, licensekey, hwid, email

Comment: In that case UPDATE table-name-here SET hwid= 'Not Set' WHERE licensekey = 'TEST-TEST-TEST=T' this query should work.

Comment: I still not understand totally what issue are you facing.

Comment: Well the issue is, it's not working. I've tried that query but it's not changing the hwid column field like it was never used before if you understand what I mean. But it needs to be where licensekey = TEST-TEST-TEST=T

Answer (score 0):

Ok Ive managed to do it, was a small error my end, I put a cap S for sent when it needed a small s.

So here is the fix for others who want to use this sort of query.

UPDATE yourtablename SET hwid = 'Not set' WHERE licensekey = 'TEST-TEST-TEST=T'